# Why does my Rails FormHelper (Formtastic) not display booleans correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I am using Formtastic and I have a simple boolean field.  In my view, I have

```
        <%= f.input :active, :label => "Enabled?", :as => :select, :include_blank => false, :collection => [ ["Yes", true], ["No", false] ] %><br />
```

It saves to the database just fine.  But when it loads, it always shows the first value ("Yes").

What am I missing?  It should default to "No" when the field is false.

Thanks for any tips.

EDIT

When I put the ["No", false] first, it works!

```
        <%= f.input :active, :label => "Enabled?", :as => :select, :include_blank => false, :collection => [ ["No", false], ["Yes", true] ] %>
```

Why would that matter?????

Answer (score 2):

Here is a submitted bug/patch on the topic

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5702-options_for_select-do-not-select-boolean-values-correctly

and it is fixed in rails >= v3.0.3

Comment: strange - I get the same problem and this is on formtastic 3.1.3 and rails 4.1.6 and rubinius 2.5.7 -

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you remove the `:include_blank => false`? Is the first option (blank) selected? If so, could the value for the attribute be `nil` and not `false`?

Comment: When I remove that, I get three options, "", "true", "false".

Comment: ...and which one is selected?

Comment: The first one.  In fact, it's always the first one UNLESS I put the negative (false) as the first in the list.  Then it works perfectly.  See my EDIT above.  I wonder if this is a bug and maybe I should submit it?

Comment: No, I think what's happening is that the value of the attribute is `nil`, not `false`. Unless you have a `default` constraint in the database, or you initialize the value in your model, the default value for a boolean attribute is `nil`. Because you turn off the blank selection with `include_blank` => false, there is no way for the form to indicate that the value is `nil`, so the form just selects the first element in the collection. Normally a boolean attribute is displayed using radio buttons or a checkbox, which don't suffer from this problem.